# How to create angular service to get data from localstorage if available otherwise call api method

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create an angular service to switch between actual API call and local storage within single method call.

component.ts

```
this.userService.getAllUsers().subscribe(data => {
      console.log('users', data); //getUser
});
```

user.service.ts

```
export class UsersService {

constructor(...){ }

getAllUsers() {
    return this.storageMap.get('users').pipe(
      switchMap(data => {
        if (data) return data;
        else return this.userStore.collection('users').valueChanges();
      })
    );
 }

saveUsers(data){
return this.storageMap.set('users', data);
}

}
```

Local storage library: @ngx-pwa/local-storage

Issues:

1. I don't have an idea how to return "data" as Observable from "getAllUsers" method if its available in storageMap.
2. How to call "saveUsers" method to save data in local storage within "getAlluser" if data is undefined.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the data from `LocalStorage` into an observable by using the RxJS [of](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/of.html) operator.

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
.
.
const observableData = of(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It helps me to achieve the results.